# Когда выполняется @Value при установке значения свойства бина

Tags: java, spring

```
@Configuration
public void SpringApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringApp.class);
    Person person = ctx.getBean("vasyaBean", Person.class);
    System.out.println(person.getName());
  }
  @Bean( name = "vasyaBean")
  public Person person() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("vasya");
    return person;
  }
}
```

---

```
@Component( "ivanBean" )
public class Person {
  private String name;
  @Value( "ivan" )
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

---

В вывод пишет `ivan`. Как спринг действует в таком случае, когда видит`@Value`?

**Update**
В доках сказано, что `@Value`обрабатывается `BeanPostProcessor`ом. Правильно ли я понимаю, что я вручную создаю бин, и прежде как конструктор вернет объект, контейнер триггерится и вызывает BeanPostProcessor? Выходит BeanPostProcessor вызывается каждый раз, как создается новый бин? Неважно компонент это или нет, он просто сканирует бин на наличие нужных ему аннотаций? Простите, что так много вопросов, но в этом случае всем этим вопросам лучше быть в кучке, чем создавать новые по отдельности)

Answer (score 0):

В самом простом случае, Spring создает бины при старте приложения, в этот момент срабатывают все `pre` и `post` процессоры Spring-а для найденых бинов. Получается, что `@Value` обрабатывается также при старте приложения. Это в общем случае. Т.е. при старте приложения, Spring создает `ApplicationContext` и наполняет его найденными бинами. Каждый бин в Spring-е является Singleton-ом (если не указано иное в описании самого бина). Если Вы попытаетесь создать экземпляр класса бина в ручную, через `new`, никакие `pre` и `post` процессоры Spring-а не сработают, Вы просто получите экземпляр класса. Т.е. всё происходит ровно так, как описано в документации.

Answer (score 0):

значение из @Value выставляется после конструирования объекта постпроцессором. В случае:

```
  @Bean( name = "vasyaBean")
  public Person person() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("vasya");
    return person;
  }
```

пост процессор перетирает ваше значение при возврате из метода person()